# VB6 : Array in Array and Array Code with string

Tags: arrays, vb6

In Javascript we can use Array in Array code or array with string like

```
strArr["str1"][2]["str3"]
strArr.str1[2].str3
```

`[2]` array with number 
`["str1"]` or `.str1` are array with string 
`["str1"][2]["str3"]` or `.str1[2].str3` are array in array

how can i do same in vb6?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how nested arrays work? Or do you want to know if VB6 supports named arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim x() as Byte

x = "a byte array filled with a string"
```

or in VB6 we have the `Mid` STATEMENT  (not to be confused with the `mid` function). This allows writing to any character in a string.

On the whole you treat a byte array as if it's a string.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim x() As Byte
    x = "David Warner is a great batsman"

    'Treating it as an array and using Chr to convert from a number to a character
    'Remember unicode is two byte per character usually
    MsgBox Chr(x(12))

    'Treating it as a string
    MsgBox Mid(x, 7, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: can you show me a sample how to use it. maybe full code for this one?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. Your question is abstract.

Comment: Ok, Im sorry. And Thanks for your answer.